# How to use a bundle in my Xcode app?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xcode4.2, bundle

I'm new to Xcode and have I've a simple question that I didn't find the answer after googling it and searching here.
I have a bundle file ("zxing.bundle") and I wanna use some of it's class in my application!
I use Xcode 4.3.2, so how can I instantiate from those classes?
Thank you

Comment: you have to add it to your library class path!

Comment: Do you mean the "Linked Frameworks and Libraries" section? I add the bundle there but classes that exist in it, were unkown yet! I try #import header files but they are also unkown!

Comment: It is in the project build section ... please see this the screen shot in this [link](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/04/04/using-open-source-static-libraries-in-xcode-4/)

Answer (score 1):

Initialize a `NSBundle` instance with the path of your bundle, and then use `-[NSBundle classNamed:]`. Alternatively, use `-[NSBundle load]` and `NSClassFromString`.